# What services would best be used to collect, transform, and store media player logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging

A video player sends the server log data about what the user has been doing (start, pause, play, playing, etc.)

Sending the logs to the server and storing them in the DB, then running queued jobs to calculate stats on these has worked... *okay*, so far.

It's clear there should be some sort of optimization here. What services provide the best custom log storage?

What would be the best manual option? Considering running some Lambda functions and storing in AWS (RDS?) manually, but wondering if the maintenance of such a service is warranted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the logs in AWS S3 (Storage) and then use AWS Glue (Transform) and AWS Athena for ad-hoc querying of different stats, this will still work out cheaper than using a traditional database approach plus it has a lot of other advantages.